# How to load two websites in one page?

Tags: webbrowser-control

I don't want to use frame or iframe because most websites are busting it nowdays.

what are the possible methods to do this?

The intended behaviour is as if like two browser controls loaded in a website.

Comment: What is your relationship with the sites? If you're connected with them they can specifically allow the embedding. If you're not ....

Comment: iframes are hip nowadays. even facebook uses them

Comment: What is the best device to call other people while I'm walking through the park? I don't want to use a cell phone because every idiot has one. Is there a radio device available where I would hold one and send another by Fedex to the person I want to call so we can have a conversation?

Comment: Peter,
The problem i have is I need to provide certain information handy when people on other sites when they go through my site. The original purpose of the frames is to do that its unfortunate that people use it for stupid reasons and it causes good things not to be able to be done. But I'm pretty sure there must be a way out for this and thats what i'm look for.

Thorsten, approach your idea and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with an iframe? What do you mean by busting (lots of websites are full of iframes)? You do not want to use iframes within an email but that is a different point!

The advantage is when people click on links within an iframe the content of the iframe gets refreshed, while if you pull the content of a webpage and then display it within a div the user will be moved on loosing the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can pull it via script (PHP / curl) and display the code from there.

or you can use good old frames, although i wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want frames, then another option is to do it server side - make your server access the pages and combine them into one response stream.

You can also so this client side using Javascript and DHTML

Comment: I like this, Is there any examples out there that I can look for.

Answer (score 0):

**fopen()** returns a file pointer:

```
$file = fopen("http://www.site.com/", "r");
```

Comment: But don't use it if you want to parse a lot of pages, use cURL instead.

Comment: A tut/code on using cURL: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl

Comment: @Radek re curl: why do you say that? Speed? Overhead? Robustness?

Comment: @Benji XVI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/filegetcontents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

Comment: Is the CURL equivalent to a browser control or it will just work for that one page.

Comment: cURL lets you work with content on remote servers including POST and GET form posting, SSL support, HTTP authentication, session and cookie handling. Check out the PHP implementation and what it can do for you.